# Android custom control xml id reference

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

im creating a custom control for Xamarin/Android in C#

It needs to have a reference to 2 of their childs set in xml layout, so i tried this.

```
  <declare-styleable name="CustomControl">
    <attr name="firstViewReference" format="reference" />
    <attr name="SecondViewReference" format="reference" />
  </declare-styleable>
```

Then in code im doing this to retrieve the values:

```
   TypedArray a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(this.xmlAttrs, Resource.Styleable.CustomControl);
   int aid =a.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.CustomControl_firstViewReference,0);
```

But the call to getResourceId is always returning the error value (0 here).

My xml:

```
    <CustomControl xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:firstViewReference="@+id/firstView">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/firstView"/>
    </CustomControl>
```

Is there something wrong? why im not getting the id for my View set as firstViewReference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `this.xmlAttrs`? post more code as now its unclear where you are using `ObtainStyledAttributes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
 TypedArray a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(this.xmlAttrs, Resource.Styleable.CustomControl);
   int aid =a.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.CustomControl_firstViewReference,0);
```

Was in OnFinishInflate, as my view needs to access its childs so i have to wait until it finish inflating.

I put that code right in the view constructor and now its returning the correct id.

Of course i need to call findViewById in OnFinishInflate or it will return null.

The solution was to create the TypedArray on the constructor instead of OnFinishInflate , can someone point out why is this needed? this.xmlAttrs is the AttributeSet received in constructor.

Comment: this is because the `LayoutInflater` shares the same `AttributeSet` when inflating all of the views

Comment: So i can only get the attributes before it starts to parse the next element? shouldnt that be at the docs?

Comment: yes, it should be, but you know... they will do it "mañana"